# Update Using Case in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a scenario where I want to update multiple columns of first table from multiple rows of second table. But the case only updates from first row from second table.

Any help to achieve this with out using cursor?

```
create table Table1 (ColA varchar(20), ColB varchar(20), ColC varchar(20))

insert into Table1 values (1, null, null)

create table Table2 (ColA varchar(20), ColB varchar(20), ColValue varchar(20))

insert into Table2 values (1, 2, 'X'), (1, 3, 'Y')

update Table1 
set ColB = case 
              when T1.ColB = 2 
                 then T1.ColValue 
                 else T0.ColB 
           end,
    ColC = case 
              when T1.ColB = 3 
                 then T1.ColValue 
                 else T0.ColC 
           end
from Table1 T0 
inner join Table2 T1 on T0.ColA = T1.ColA

select * from Table1
```

Looking at the result, the statement has updated only `ColB`

Answer (score 0):

There a number of ways that this could be done, here is one:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET ColB = t2.ColValue
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ColB = 2) AS t2
     ON t1.ColA = t2.ColA;

 UPDATE t1
   SET ColC = t2.ColValue
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ColB = 3) AS t2
     ON t1.ColA = t2.ColA;
```

This does involve two passes over each table, but the syntax is very simple which is always a bonus.

If it is necessary to use a single statement try like this:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET ColB = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ColValue FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ColA = t1.ColA AND Table2.ColB = 2), t1.ColB),
       ColC = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ColValue FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ColA = t1.ColA AND Table2.ColB = 3), t1.ColC),
       ...
   FROM Table1 AS t1;
```

Using `ISNULL()` to avoid updating where there is nothing in `Table2`.

Comment: This is simple, but i will have 12 to 20 columns where i need to set value based on Type from other table. Writing one update for each column is not a good idea.

Comment: @RAJUSAGI Updated to show a single statement. This is why it helps to include all pertinent details in the original question : )

Comment: thank you for update. I used the same logic. the problem is the second table itself a complicated query with many conditions. I used Common table expression which was very helpful in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET ColB = CASE WHEN T1.ColValue IS NOT NULL
                   THEN T1.ColValue 
                   ELSE T0.ColB 
           END,
    ColC = CASE WHEN T2.ColValue IS NOT NULL
                   THEN T2.ColValue 
                   ELSE T0.ColC 
           END
FROM Table1 T0 
INNER JOIN Table2 T1 ON T0.ColA = T1.ColA AND T1.ColB = 2
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T0.ColA = T2.ColA AND T2.ColB = 3
```

Comment: No. I will have to update more than 20 columns, using join for each case makes code looks complicated

Answer (score 0):

Issue is : you are  trying to update same row multiple times in the same query.

you can user Merge statement

refer

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/321926/merge-will-update-row-more-than-once-if-target-is-view-with-an-instead-of-trigger

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
update Table1
    set ColB =
        (
        select max(case when t2.ColB = 2 then t2.ColValue else t1.ColB end)
        from Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ColA = t2.ColA
        ),
    ColC =
        (
        select max(case when t2.ColB = 3 then t2.ColValue else t1.ColB end)
        from Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ColA = t2.ColA
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) with the second table to unify the results to update, as:

```
update Table1 set
    ColB = T1.ColB_Y,
    ColC = T1.ColC_Y
from Table1 T0
inner join 
(select ColA
    , [2] as ColB_Y
    , [3] as ColC_Y
 from 
    (select * from Table2) X
 pivot (
    max(ColValue)
    for ColB in ([2],[3])
 ) Y) T1 on T1.ColA = T0.ColA
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E2we1_za)